# Whats the difference between .match("") and .match(/^$/)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I had a problem where I was checking for empty HTML content within a certain element. When I used

```
someElement.trim().match("")
```

I would sometimes get true as a result even though the HTML content was empty. I changed it to

```
someElement.trim().match(/^$/)
```

and it now seems to always return the correct boolean value.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve] with example input and expected output

Comment: `""` doesn't match anything. `/^$/` matches an empty line

Comment: someElement already has .html() applied to it -> someElement.html().trim().match()

Comment: `""` means nothing. Nothing exists in anything. `^$` means beginning of input string meets end of it. Making sure there are no characters in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match('')` is the same as `match(new RegExp(''))` and `new RegExp('')` returns `/(?:)/` which matches an empty string as it is not anchored if a substring matched it returns `true`. Whereas `/^$/` is anchored `^` matches the beginning and `$` the end of input.

Other examples:

```
# true
'hello'.match('h')
'hello'.match('e')

# false
'hello'.match('^e$')
```